# Unlocked phenom showing as athlon

Tags: cpu, amd-phenom, amd-athlon

I recently successfully unlocked the other 2 cores on my AMD phenom II x2 b59 CPU. From what I know it is equivalent to a phenom II x4 965. I'm not complaining (it gave me a very good performance boost) but I am curious because it shows up on my computer as an Athlon II x4 559. Why is it showing up as that instead of a phenom II x4 965?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CPU is still an AMD Phenom II x2 b59 , however you unlocked the 2 de-activated cores, essentially making it an AMD Phenom II **x4** b59.

Note: Unlocking the locked cores does not mean they will work as intended or overclock well.

It is more than likely that whichever program you are using to view system specs (Speccy, BIOS, CPU-Z, HWMonitor), it may list it as an Athlon CPU, but in reality it is just a Phenom with the other 2 cores unlocked, and there is a chance those 2 cores may not even work. Hence why it is sent to the dual-core or tri-core bucket to be sorted out.

In this case, the difference in names is semantic only.